# We can't generate the sitemap right now, due to missing query?

Tags: magento-2.1, sitemaps

I recently set my site live, and I was attempting to setup the sitemap.xml file, unfortunately it generates the (what seems common) and vague error "We can't generate the sitemap right now."

A little info first:
Magento CE 2.1.3, php 7.0.16, nginx hosted service.

However, when I look into my log files, this error is generated in the system.log file:

```
    [2017-03-10 20:38:13] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't2_name.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`updated_at`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` AS `url`, IFNULL(t2_name.value, t1_name.value) AS `name`, IFNULL(t2_thumbnail.value, t1_thumbnail.value) AS `thumbnail` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `w` ON e.entity_id = w.product_id
 LEFT JOIN `url_rewrite` ON e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1 AND url_rewrite.metadata IS NULL AND url_rewrite.store_id = '31' AND url_rewrite.entity_type = 'product'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t1_visibility` ON e.entity_id = t1_visibility.entity_id AND t1_visibility.store_id = 0 AND t1_visibility.attribute_id = '99'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t2_visibility` ON t1_visibility.entity_id = t2_visibility.entity_id AND t1_visibility.attribute_id = t2_visibility.attribute_id AND t2_visibility.store_id = '31'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t1_status` ON e.entity_id = t1_status.entity_id AND t1_status.store_id = 0 AND t1_status.attribute_id = '97'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t2_status` ON t1_status.entity_id = t2_status.entity_id AND t1_status.attribute_id = t2_status.attribute_id AND t2_status.store_id = '31'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t1_name` ON e.entity_id = t1_name.entity_id AND t1_name.store_id = 0 AND t1_name.attribute_id = '73'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t1_thumbnail` ON e.entity_id = t1_thumbnail.entity_id AND t1_thumbnail.store_id = 0 AND t1_thumbnail.attribute_id = '89' WHERE (w.website_id = '1') AND ((IF(t2_visibility.value_id > 0, t2_visibility.value, t1_visibility.value)) IN(3, 2, 4)) AND ((IF(t2_status.value_id > 0, t2_status.value, t1_status.value)) IN(1))
Trace: #0 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#4 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#5 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#6 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php(289): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
#7 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php(245): Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product->getCollection('31')
#8 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php(338): Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap->_initSitemapItems()
#9 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Controller/Adminhtml/Sitemap/Generate.php(27): Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap->generateXml()
#10 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate->execute()
#11 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#14 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sitemap...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#15 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sitemap...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#18 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/userhome/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Sitemap/Controller/Adminhtml/Sitemap/Generate/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Generate\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#25 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/userhome/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/userhome/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /home/userhome/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there is a thread where is mentioned the same query:

- https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/cannot-generate-sitemap/td-p/41623

There is also ticket open with the same issue:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8671

By looking the query then t2_name is not found therein joins.

This is added to select in

```
vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php::getCollection
```

As also GitHub issues say then this is added only when you have enabled "Add Images to Sitemap".

You should try to disable this option to have at least sitemap without image info.

Comment: Where is the"Add Images into Sitemap" setting?

Comment: nvm:  Stores > Configuration > Catalog > XML SiteMap , Product Options, set Add Images into Sitemap to none.

Comment: Thank you btw, this DID solve my problem (I'm not too concerned with images not being in the sitemap)